# useState value become undefined after page refreshing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Right now i'm learning React+Redux
And  i am doing a training project.

There are several useState hooks in the container that, thanks to MapStateToProps, get initial states from props. These states are the values of several imputes.

if I go to the form by reference, it successfully pulls the data into imputes,
but if I refresh the page, the imputes become empty and the hook values are **undefined** although props have a value

img of devtools https://i.ibb.co/T0sGBdM/1.png

```
const PostEditorContainer = (props) => {

  const {fetchPosts,_id,text,title,imageUrl,history} = props;

  const [textNode,setText] = useState(text);
  const [titleNode,setTitle] = useState(title);
  const [imageUrlNode,setImageUrl] = useState(imageUrl);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  },[]);

  const updatedData = {
    imageUrl: imageUrlNode,
    title: titleNode,
    text: textNode,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <HeaderBlock/>

      <AddForm
        title={titleNode}
        imageUrl={imageUrlNode}
        text={textNode}

        onChangeImage={e =>
          setImageUrl(e.target.value)
        }
        onChangeText={e =>
          setText(e.target.value)
        }
        onChangeTitle={e =>
          setTitle(e.target.value)
        }
        onSubmit={() => {
          PostApi.put(_id,updatedData)    
        }}
       />
    </>
  )
};


const mapStateToProps = ({posts},{match: {params:{id}}}) => {
  return posts.posts.filter(item => item._id === id)[0]
  console.log(posts);
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps,PostListActions)(PostEditorContainer)
)
```

actions for more understing

```
const PostListActions = {
  showPosts: (posts) => {
    return {
      type: "POSTS:SET_POSTS",
      payload: posts
    }
  },

  fetchPosts: () => dispatch => {
    PostApi.get().then(({data}) => {
      dispatch(PostListActions.showPosts(data))
    })
  },

};

export default PostListActions;
```

Store img https://i.ibb.co/R7pMqW0/2.png

Comment: How does your redux state get set up?

Comment: State receives data from get request to the server

Comment: @AntonSokolov please provide cleaner code! and you can use react-redux hooks